# Can we create flashing red circle around user location in mapview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mapkit

Can we create flashing red circle around user location instead of blue (default) ? And also make user location pinpoint with red bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the viewForAnnotation method, check for the user location annotation.
2. Create a uiimageview and set the property animationImages to the different images that conform the red flashing circle, and call startAnimating.
3. Add the uiimageview to a mkannotationview.
4. Return the mkannotationview for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Make 3-4 concentric circle images of certain thickness and add them on user location annotationview. then for each of them

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f 
                                     animations:^{
subView.frame = CGRectFrame();//Initail frame
                                         subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
                                         subView.alpha = 0;
                                     }
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                         //Additional code
                                     }];
```

here, subView is one of circle images. I have not tested above but should work. Maybe you can add/remove some of circle images on the way of animation to get better look

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not aware much about Mapviews... but if you can use GIF image which can have same effect as flashing color then you can just use that...

I had found a great link which plays GIF images... if you can modify it somehow to use with yours situation....

Follow the Git Link: https://github.com/jamesu/glgif

hope if it helps you...

**EDIT**

This link may be useful to you : http://iphonebcit.wordpress.com/iphone-map-kit-tutorial/iphone-map-kit-tutorial2/iphone-map-kit-tutorial3/

Comment: thanks DShah.. but it uses OpenGL, And don’t want to use that.. Is there any other way ???